# Oracle SQL - Filling student graduation requirements with credits earned. (Loop or Creative Join?)

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, join

I'm a bit stumped on how to structure this query. I have two tables, one with graduation requirements (GradReq) and one with earned student credits (StoredGrades). GradReq lists each "credit bucket" and the associated course numbers that can fill it. StoredGrades lists the course number and whether the student passed the course. Theoretical examples are below.

```
GradReq:
CreditBucket   CourseNumber
Algebra I        100000
Algebra I        100001
Algebra II       100001
Algebra II       100002

StoredGrades:
CourseNumber   Passed   StudentID
100001            1       30003
```

The issue I'm having is that with a standard (left)join both the Algebra I and Algebra II credit buckets will be filled for student 30003 when really that credit can only be used once. Any ideas?

I'm thinking it might be best to loop through each of the credit buckets and evaluate them one at a time, but I'm not sure how that would look. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the desired result set?

Comment: The way I read this data, the student has satisfied both the `Algebra I` and `Algebra II` credit requirements by passing course `100001`. If you want to give only one "credit bucket" for course `100001` you'll need a way to distinguish which bucket they get - for example if I were Student `30003` I'd want it to show as `Algebra II` rather than `Algebra I` on my transcript.

Comment: A two-step process that matches singletons first would probably be best.   Loop or no, you'll also need some way to determine priority of assignment of course to credit and vice versa where multiple courses can satisfy a requirement or where a course can satisy multiple requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The data model that you currently have can only answer eligibility questions such as "Which requirements does student1 satisfy). When you do an outer join, you get 2 results, which is correct. Student 1 has finished one course, which satisfies his grad requirement for Algebra1 or Algebra2.

The actual credit association that you are trying to implement is usually done in a different entity/table. Something like...

```
GradReqUsed (or GradReqConsumtion, perhaps?)

CreditBucket  CourseNumber StudentID

Algebra I     100001       30003
```

Which basically means the student will have 100001 counted towards the Algebra1 bucket.